# How to create provisioning profile to develop on personal device using free developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode8, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

When I plug my iPhone in and try to run using Xcode 8.1 and deploying to iOS 10.1 I get a couple errors:

`Unable to add device 'My iPhone' because the team has already reached the maximum number of iPhone devices.`

`No profiles for <my bundle ID> were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching <my bundle ID>.`

`Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'`

I'm not sure why I'm getting the team has already reached the maximum number of iPhone devices error. To my knowledge I only have one and it's the one I'm trying to use now. In my https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage this is what it shows: [image: devices] Is this the right place for maintaining the iPhone devices on my team and if not where do I do that?

I think the main issue is that I don't have a provisioning profile and am not quite sure how to make one.

I go to my account in the preferences and I already have a signing identity  but don't know how to create a provisioning profile. [image: accounts tab]

How can I create a new provisioning profile to continue developing on my personal device? Thanks!

Comment: Connect the phone to the computer and build-and-run the project onto the phone again.

Comment: Please me explicit as to what symptoms you are getting.  Post exact error messages, etc.

Comment: Oh, but you totally failed to reveal this in your original question: "the team has already reached the maximum number of iPhone devices." That is pretty clear.

Comment: @matt Where can I see the iPhone devices my team? To my knowledge I should only have one and it is the same phone I'm connecting now.

Comment: Hmm, I would look to see this at the member center (portal), but I think that without a paid membership you can't do that.

Comment: @matt yeah... I can't find anything on the issue. Surely I'm not the only one to experience this

Comment: Well, the point is that you've reached some kind of limit. How long have you been using the free account? You couldn't expect that to go on forever. Time to bite the bullet and join the Dark Side like everyone else here...

Comment: @matt 7 days :/. The lack of documentation on Apple's end it quite infuriating.

Comment: Okay, that's definitely not very long. I used a free account experimentally for much longer than that.

Comment: Are you using some catch-all bundle ID? Try using a real bundle ID that uses your real name.

Comment: @matt not quite sure what you mean by catch-all but I've changed the bundle ID to include my name and still getting the same errors.

Comment: Well it was just a guess. :( And there is no one else on your Team? In that case, I'm out of ideas...

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up calling Apple Developer Support and they say because the apple ID I'm trying to use was previously (many years ago) attached to a paid account and that this free developer account is new, there isn't a way to use this apple ID with the free developer account. They recommend I create a new apple ID (which I know isn't optimal) but it works now.